# How to Uninstall Blender Software

Tags: python

I installed Blender for a project working on and it's way more than I need. I'd like to uninstall it, but can't figure out how to do so. It's not showing up in Programs (using Windows 9) and I can't find instructions on how to remove it in the Blender documentation. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as as Windows 9,you probably mean Windows 10. Anyway maybe you just downloaded the zipped portable version, in which case all you have to do is delete the folder you extracted it to.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing that it's not in the list of programs, it seems like you downloaded the zip version, rather than the msi version, which means blender isn't actually installed on your system.

Just delete the folder where blender.exe is, and it's gone!