# Can installing the latest build of Blender work to replace a previous build?

Tags: installation

I need to replace Blender 2.80, which I am unable to uninstall with Blender 2.82a.

Comment: To get a better reply I provide this info: Blender 2.80 does not have a way to uninstall it on my PC. There is no uninstaller, and it does not appear in the Installed Programs list of the Control Panel.

Comment: Related: [How to Uninstall Blender Software](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52020/78972)

Comment: Blender Installer doesn't automatically remove older versions. It also useful to have one older version installed, just in case :).